# Steganography from Audio File using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, steganography

I am trying to solve a problem wherein the I have to find a text in the audio file that is being uploaded on web site. The text is hidden in the binary code of audio file as plain text only. I have to do it using JavaScript only when the audio is up to play.

While the audio player is working fine, I cannot 'get inside' the audio file binary data.

So far what I did was,

```
function playMusic() {
  if (!isPaused) {
    player.src = URL.createObjectURL(songs[currentSong]);
    fetch(player.src).then(function (response) {
      var fileAsBlob = response.blob();
      console.log(fileAsBlob);
    });
```

The output I get is :

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Blob
size: 6423486
type: "audio/mpeg"
__proto__: Blob
arrayBuffer: ƒ arrayBuffer()
size: (...)
slice: ƒ slice()
stream: ƒ stream()
text: ƒ text()
type: (...)
constructor: ƒ Blob()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Blob"
get size: ƒ size()
get type: ƒ type()
__proto__: Object
```

But I am unable to move forward from here. I didn't find a way to convert it into string or any format in which I can check whether the binary data contains the said text.

I tried file reading, but it doesn't accept the above variable as Blob. So cannot use readAsText or readAsArrayBuffer.

Also tried creating the variable as an instance of Blob, but I have issue with 'type : 'audio/*' as it is not accepted while I am not sure which format the audio file will be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`blob()` returns a promise, so you'll want to either use `await` or `then`. Also, to get at the contents there's another method on `blob` called `text`, which also returns a promise. So, maybe try this, see if you can work with either of those outputs:

```
function playMusic() {
  if (!isPaused) {
    player.src = URL.createObjectURL(songs[currentSong]);
    fetch(player.src).then(function (response) {
      response.blob().then(function(fileAsBlob) {
        console.log(fileAsBlob);
        fileAsBlob.text(function(fileAsText) {
          console.log(fileAsText);
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: I tried some similar approach but since file size remains high, it kind of goes into limbo. Tried upvoting your answer, but lower creatures like me are not given option for it.Thanks for the reply though. I solved it, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the solution. My problem was that I had to find a FileID, i.e. the text started with FileID: "id data" and I had to fetch the id data.

My solution:

```
function playMusic() {
  if (!isPaused) {
    player.src = URL.createObjectURL(songs[currentSong]);
    let songBArray = new File([songs[currentSong]], "name");

    let fReader = new FileReader();
    fReader.readAsText(songBArray);
    fReader.onload = function (ev) {
      if (fReader.result.indexOf("FileID:")) {
        var n = fReader.result.indexOf("FileID:");
        let fileID = "";
        for (let j = n + 7; ; j++) {
          var ch = fReader.result[j];

          if ((ch >= "0" && ch <= "9") || (ch >= "A" && ch <= "Z")) {
            fileID += ch;
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }
        console.log(fileID);
      }
    };
  }
```